# Integrand evaluating to non-numerical values

Tags: numerical-integration

I have solved a system of equations using NDSolve just fine. From there, I can plot the solutions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$, as well as its derivatives, just fine. But, when I want to evaluate the energy density for v, defined as $E(x)=\frac{\alpha}{2}(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})^2+\beta((v^2-1)^2+\epsilon_2v)$, as well as the total energy, $\int_{0}^{10}E(x)dx$, I run into the following problem:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand energiephi6 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,10}}."
```

Here's the code:

```
eps = 1/4;
eps2 = 1/10;
eps3 = 1/10;
alpha = 1;
beta = 3;
a = 5.6294;
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[x], x, 
  x] == -(6 u[x]^5 - (8 + 4 eps) u[x]^3 + (2 + 4 eps) u[
      x] + (v[x]^4 - 2 v[x]^2 + eps2*v[x] + 1)*2 u[
       x]/(u[x]^2 + eps3)^2), 
alpha*D[v[x], x, 
   x] == -beta (4 v[x]^3 - 4 v[x] + eps2)/(u[x]^2 + eps3), 
u[0] == 0, u'[0] == a, v[0] == 1, v'[0] == 0}, {u, v}, {x, 0, 10}];
phi6n = Evaluate[v[x]] /. sol
phi6Dn = D[phi6n, x]
energiephi6[x] = 0.5*alpha*phi6Dn[x]^2 + beta ((phi6n[x]^2 - 1)^2 + eps2*phi6n);
energietotale6 = NIntegrate[energiephi6, {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[Evaluate[u[t]] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[phi6n, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[phi6Dn, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot[energiephi6, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Thus far, all I could do was to identify this line as the culprit:

```
energiephi6[x] = 0.5*alpha*phi6Dn[x]^2 + beta ((phi6n[x]^2 - 1)^2 + eps2*phi6n);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
phi6n = v[x] /. sol[[1]];
phi6Dn = D[phi6n, x];
energiephi6 = 0.5*alpha*phi6Dn^2 + beta ((phi6n^2 - 1)^2 + eps2*phi6n);
energietotale6 = NIntegrate[energiephi6, {x, 0, 10}]
Plot[energiephi6, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]